# Echo results on same line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have my echo results on the same line after being ran on the page. The code below works, but displays the price on one line, price with discount on the next, and the button on another.

```
<strike>$<?php echo number_format($row->price,2);?> USD</strike>
<h3>$<?php 
    $sale_price = $row->price -(($row->price /100) * $row->discount);
    echo number_format($sale_price,2);
    ?> USD
</h3>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> <b>View Product</b>
</button>
```

Anyone have suggestions to make it all on the same line so their right next to each other? I'm sure its a simple fix, but I've tried researching and haven't come across something yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your h3 styled to `display: inline` in CSS?

Comment: Was not, what you had before you edited code wise fixed it

Comment: Small advise - process your data outside of HTML markup, to keep it clean: <?php $a = ...; $b = ...; $c = ...; <strike>echo $a</strike><h3>echo $b</h3> ?> for example - it should help to make your code more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$sale_price = $row->price - (($row->price /100) * $row->discount);

echo "<h3><strike>" . number_format($row->price,2) . " USD </strike> " . number_format($sale_price,2) . " USD</h3>";

?>
```

or this perhaps:

```
$<?php $sale_price = $row->price - (($row->price /100) * $row->discount);?>

<h3><strike>$<?php echo number_format($row->price,2);?> USD </strike>$<?php echo number_format($sale_price,2);?> USD</h3>
```

The problem is mostly in the place where you use the `<h3>` tags, and because you have put the original price outside of that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use css, i.E.:

```
strike, h3 { float: left; }
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the usage of "h3"  It's breaking the line.  It always does.

Copy that style into a class and use a "span class='h3class'" instead.
That will solve your problem.

Comment: Using `h3` could be a SEO choice. By replacing it with a span you lose it.

Comment: That's a good point.  Considering that it really didn't appear to actually BE any sort of a header, which would actually work against SEO, I didn't think of it that way.